# Sequence musical event with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, generative-art

I would like to sequence musical events with web audio, to do a simple musical piece. I'm just gettin started with web audio & I'm looking for tips or pointers in the right direction to be able to sequence simple events one after the other. I know how to make a playable synth with web audio but what i want is to make a small composition:

Example of what I mean by sequencing events (or making a composition):

1- at time 0 : 1 oscillator is paying a part that will end after 3 minutes.
2- after 1 minute another oscillator starts another part that will stop after 30 sec.
3- after 2 minutes an audio file starts (let's say a prerecorded bass)

How do we sequence (start & stop) different parts at a different time ?

I know how to make a synth with web audio but i would like to time events in a timeline.
Where should I start ?

I guess my question is "what is the best way to trigger a function a certain amount of time after another one or when one is finished with Web Audio?"

thx!

Comment: Sadly this question is a little too open ended for SO. My personal recommendation is to look at wrappers for web audio and se if there is already an implementation of what you’re looking for . E.g [P5js](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Score), [Elementary](https://www.elementary.audio/)

Comment: @fdcpp I guess my question is "what is the best way to trigger a function a certain amount of time after another one or when one is finished with Web Audio?

Comment: There are a lot of examples in the net how to do this. If you still need help after you have started your own coding, please share a minimal code example that shows your actual issue.

Comment: Check this nice tutorial to start with web audio ([link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)).